# Open Weather Api (Show weather icon)

Tags: javascript, html, api, vue.js, weather

Hello community back to you again. I am playing with the openweather API and i am building a simple weather app. I have an issue and i can't show the weather conditions icon for each city.

I pushed every icon id in a newArray and i am trying to show it using the url but without luck http://openweathermap.org/img/w/10d.png

Any suggestion?Thanks in advance

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {

  test: [],
  image: [],
  newArray:[],
  message: "",
  url: "",
  
 },
 created: function () {
  this.getData();
  this.cities();
 
  },
        methods: {
  getData: function () {
   var fetchConfig =
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/i8run", {
     method: "GET",
     headers: new Headers({})
    }).then(function (response) {
     if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
     }
    }).then(function (json) {
     console.log("My json", json)

     app.test = json.list;
     console.log(app.test);
          app.pushAnArr();
   

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
    })
  },
   
  cities: function () {
   var fetchConfig =
    fetch("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=10772849-8270b213e517e422b036ea0fd&q=city", {
     method: "GET",
     headers: new Headers({})
    }).then(function (response) {
     if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
     }
    }).then(function (json) {
     console.log("My json", json)

     app.image = json.hits;
     console.log(app.image);
    

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
    })
  },
   
  pushAnArr: function(){
  for(var i=0; i<app.test.length; i++){
   
   app.newArray.push(app.test[i].weather[0].icon);
   
   
  }
      console.log(app.newArray); 

  
  }
   
   
 }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
   <div v-for="item in newArray" :key="item.id" class="thecard">
                      {{item}}
       <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/item.png" >
        </div>
                
 </div>

  


  
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are using the static URL `http://openweathermap.org/img/w/item.png` every single time. Maybe you want to put your `{{item}}` placeholder in there somewhere as well …?

Comment: You're definitely trying to show src="http://openweathermap.org/img/w/item.png", aren't you?

Comment: There is a free public weather api called **weatherDB**, which is more easy and simple to implement You can try it once. Site: http://weatherdbi.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use curlies `{{item}}` in attributes.

**Use:**

```
<img v-bind:src="'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + item + '.png' "  />
```

```js
var app = new Vue({
 el: "#app",
 data: {

  test: [],
  image: [],
  newArray:[],
  message: "",
  url: "",
  
 },
 created: function () {
  this.getData();
  this.cities();
 
  },
        methods: {
  getData: function () {
   var fetchConfig =
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/i8run", {
     method: "GET",
     headers: new Headers({})
    }).then(function (response) {
     if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
     }
    }).then(function (json) {
     console.log("My json", json)

     app.test = json.list;
     console.log(app.test);
          app.pushAnArr();
   

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
    })
  },
   
  cities: function () {
   var fetchConfig =
    fetch("https://pixabay.com/api/?key=10772849-8270b213e517e422b036ea0fd&q=city", {
     method: "GET",
     headers: new Headers({})
    }).then(function (response) {
     if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
     }
    }).then(function (json) {
     console.log("My json", json)

     app.image = json.hits;
     console.log(app.image);
    

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
     console.log(error);
    })
  },
   
  pushAnArr: function(){
  for(var i=0; i<app.test.length; i++){
   
   app.newArray.push(app.test[i].weather[0].icon);
   
   
  }
      console.log(app.newArray); 

  
  }
   
   
 }
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
   <div v-for="item in newArray" :key="item.id" class="thecard">
                      {{item}}
       <img v-bind:src="'http://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + item + '.png' "  />
        </div>
                
 </div>

  


  
 <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much . I didn't use {{}} in my code was just a kind of testing ,your solution works. :) :)